# Group chat appears invisible for Windows 10 users of Skype for Business

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-10, lync-2013, skype, skype-for-business-2016

Recently moved to Office 365 which included a move from on-premise to cloud Skype for Business (SFB). One frustrating issue we have with this is our client machines (mostly Windows 10) cannot see the content of a group chat. It is possible to see a person typing, but when they enter their text nothing appears for those effected peoples. Does anyone provide any advice for correcting this situation?

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify a couple of points:
-Skype Client version
-Skype Client software type (MSI, or Click-to-Run package)
-"Group Chat" type.  Is this Persistent Chat (a lync/skype on-premise feature, not available in cloud service), or just regular multi-party IM conversation?

I will say I use Windows 10 and S4B online (O365) and have not seen this issue.  I run the "Office 365", click-to-run architecture client version.  I am also an outlier in my environment, the rest are Win 7.

Comment: SFB Version 16.0.6001.1054 64-bit
Click-to-Run install
Just regular multi-party group IM conversation

Thanks